# How to configure identity server 4 to include JTI claim in generated token?

Tags: identityserver4

Is there a way to configure Identity Server 4 so that it will automatically include the JTI (unique identifier) claim in the generated token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was easier than I originally thought..

For each identity server Client instance, there is a "IncludeJwtId" property that defaults to false.  You need to set this to true if you want the JTI in your access token.

[Identity Server Client Documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation now says `IncludeJwtId` defaults to `true`. [Identity Server Client Documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/client.html)